# How to properly logout from GWT app to avoid browser loading cached data?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a corporate web app built on GWT that gets access via an external authentication module. My problem is :

- I log to the application using the login page.
- I get directed (with reverse-proxy rules) to my Tomcat server where I load my GWT application.
- Work with the app.
- I log out of the application.
- When I try to log back in, I do not get the login page.

If I type the URL of the login page again, the browser starts loading cached data I do not get to the login page. I have to hit reload to get to the login page. How can this be? What is so special about F5 that tells the browser not to use the cache?

I know the proxy does not get hit by any of my requests, meaning all the browser is doing is loading cached elements.

Someone has any clues?

Comment: Must be something to do with HTTP caching semantics. If things are not cacheable, make sure you send the appropriate HTTP headers.

Comment: Just noticed that if I log in then I shut down the reverse-proxy and then type the URL on a page where I was already logged in I get a behaviour where the browser is loading back from cache but hangs.

Comment: I believe I need to mark one key GWT element as "not cacheable" say the HTML entry page.

Comment: Any password-protected asset should be non-cacheable. You get it for free with HTTP authentication, but have to enforce it when using cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't clearly understand your problem, but I think I had a similar one. I hope it will be helpful for you.

I had my GwtPage.html and all the GWT stuff secured in web.xml.

When I visited http://example.com/GwtPage.html for the first time the container's security sent me to the login.jsp. And after login was done I was sent to the GwtPage.html, so all was fine.

But for the second time the GwtPage.html was cached by browser and the container didn't sent me the login.jsp. So I have done the following:
I created index.jsp with only one line:

```
<%
    response.sendRedirect("GwtPage.html");
%>
```

And added it to the secured resources list.

Browsers don't cache it and so the container always send me the login page.

And the second benefit is that GwtPage.html remained cached by browsers, what is very good cause it is quite heavy.

My web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Security -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Index Page</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>    
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Main Page</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/GwtPage.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Gwt entrails</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Gwt/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>VIEWER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/LoginForm.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/LoginError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
After logout GWT module not started.

```
<a id="logout" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>
```

The solution is very simple, it should be automatically refreshed before open a login page

in **spring-security.xml**

`<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.html"/>`

**logout.html**

```
<head lang="en">
  <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;  url=login.html">
</head>
```